# shopware 6 admin module for app not showing app in menu

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I made a shopware app and in manifest.xml i added the tag for a admin module:

```
 <admin>
        <module name="VisualSearchAdminModule"
                parent="sw-extension"
                source="http://localhost:8080/admin/shopware"
                position="50"
        >
            <label>Visual Search</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Visual Search</label>
        </module>
    </admin>
```

Do you have any idea why the admin module is not showing in the menu ?

The app is installed and activated.
The module source is a valid url.

**Later Edit**

I do have the setup tag in my manifest. I posted below the entire manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Manifest/Schema/manifest-1.0.xsd">
    <meta>
        <name>VisualSearch</name>
        <label>Visual Search</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">Visual Search</label>
        <description>Visual Search app for Shopware 6</description>
        <description lang="de-DE">Visual Search app für Shopware 6</description>
        <author>Agency</author>
        <copyright>(c) by Agency</copyright>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <icon>Resources/config/plugin.png</icon>
        <license>MIT</license>
    </meta>
    <setup>
        <registrationUrl>http://myapp/auth</registrationUrl>
        <secret>visualsearchsecret</secret>
    </setup>

    <admin>
        <module name="VisualSearchAdminModule"
                parent="sw-extension"
                source="http://myapp/admin/shopware"
                position="50">
            <label>Visual Search</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Visual Search</label>
        </module>
    </admin>

    <permissions>
        <read>product</read>
    </permissions>

    <webhooks>
        <webhook name="app-activated" url="http://myapp/api/shop/activate" event="app.activated"/>
        <webhook name="app-deactivated" url="http://myapp/api/shop/deactivate" event="app.deactivated"/>
        <webhook name="app-deleted" url="http://myapp/api/shop/delete" event="app.deleted"/>
    </webhooks>

</manifest>
```

The registration for the app works ok.
But the admin module doesn't show in shopware admin menu.

Answer (score 1):

To register admin modules, your app currently must have a [setup segment to register with an external web service](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide#setup), even if it is a private app. Otherwise the modules will just be ignored.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/master/src/Core/Framework/App/Manifest/Schema/manifest-1.0.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <setup>
        <registrationUrl>http://localhost/register.php</registrationUrl>
        <secret>verysecret</secret>
    </setup>
    <admin>
        <module name="exampleModule"
                source="https://example.com/promotion/view/promotion-module"
                parent="sw-marketing"
                position="50"
        >
            <label>Example module</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Beispiel Modul</label>
        </module>
    </admin>
</manifest>
```

Here's a minimal example for a `register.php`

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$query = $request->query->all();
$proof = \hash_hmac(
    'sha256',
    $query['shop-id'] . $query['shop-url'] . 'TestApp',
    'verysecret'
);

$response = new JsonResponse([
    'proof' => $proof,
    'secret' => 'verysecret',
    'confirmation_url' => 'http://localhost/confirm.php'
]);

$response->send();
```

Exchange `TestApp` for the name of your app.

Comment: The registration for the app works ok. But the admin module doesn't show in shopware admin menu. I added the entire manifest.xml file to the question.